# Case Sensitive Directory Path in Windows

Tags: c, ane

I have reviewed the questions/answers asking whether or not directory/file names are case sensitive in a Windows environment as well as those discussing a need for case-sensitive searching [usually in Python, not C], so I think I understand the essential facts, but none of the postings include my particular application architecture, and the problem I am having resolving the problem.
So, let me briefly explain the application architecture of which I am speaking.  The heart of the application is built using Adobe AIR. Yes, that means that much of the U/I involves the Flex framework, but the file handling problem I am needing help with has no dependency upon the Flex U/I part of the application.
As I am trying to process a very large list of recursive directory structures, I am using the low level C RunTime API via a well-behaved mechanism which AIR provides for such cases where access to the host's Native Environment is needed.

The suite of functions which I am using is FindFileFirst, FindFileNext and FindClose.  If I write a stand-alone test program, it nicely lists the directories, sub-directories and files. The case of the directories and files is correctly shown -- just as they are correctly shown in Windows Explorer, or using the dir command.

If, however, I launch precisely the same function via the Adobe ANE interface, I receive exactly the same output with the exception that all directory names will be reduced to lower case.

Now, I should clarify that when this code is being executed as a Native Extension, it is not passing data back to AIR, it is directly outputting the results in a file that is opened and closed entirely in the CRT world, so we are not talking about any sort of communication confusion via the passing of either text or byte arrays between two different worlds.

Without kludging up this forum with lots and lots of extraneous code, I think what will help anyone who is able to help me is these snippets:

```
// This is where the output gets written.
FILE* textFile = _wfopen (L"Peek.txt", L"wt,ccs=UTF8");

WIN32_FIND_DATAW fdf;
HANDLE find = NULL;
wchar_t fullPath[2048];

// I am just showing the third argument as a literal to exemplify
// what, in reality is passed into the recursively-called function as
// a variable.
wsprintf (fullPath, L"\\\\?\\%ls\\*.*", L"F:\\");
hFind = FindFirstFile (fullPath, &fdf);

// After checking for success there appears a do..while loop
// inside which there is the expected check for the "." and ".."
// pseudo directories and a test of fdf.dwFileAttributes for
// file versus sub-directory.
// When the NextFile is a file a function is called to format
// the output in the textFile, like this:

fwprintf (textF, L"%ls\t%ls\t%2.2x\t%4d/%02d/%02d/%02d/%02d/%02d  \t%9ld.\n",
     parentPath, fdf.cFileName,
    (fdf.dwFileAttributes & 0x0f),
    st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay,
    st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond,
    fSize);
```

At that point parentPath will be a concatenated wide character string and
the other file attributes will be of the types shown.

So, to summarize:  All of this code works perfectly if I just write a stand-alone test.  When, however, the code is running as a task called from an Adobe ANE, the names of all the sub-directory parts are reduced to lower case.  I have tested every combination of file type attribute -- binary and text and encoding -- UTF-8 and UTF-16LE, but no matter what configuration I choose, the result remains the same:  Standalone the API delivers case-correct strings, running as a task in a dll invoked from AIR, the same API delivers only lower-case strings.

Comment: You should use a debugger to check what the `FindFirst*` functions return in both cases. If under the ANE case the names are all lowercase, then ANE intercepts the `FindFirst*` calls in some way.

Comment: Hard to imagine ANE would patch FindFirst/NextFile() but that's what it sounds like.  Might be a hack to deal with the difference between Unix and Windows.  Not using the ` \\?\\` prefix might have an affect.  SHGetFileInfo() might provide a workaround.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

First, my thanks to Messrs Ogilvie and Passant for helpful suggestions.

Second, I apologize for not really knowing the protocol here as a very infrequent visitor.  If I am supposed to flag either response as helpful and therefore correct, let these words at least reflect that fact.

I am providing an answer which was discovered by taking the advice above.

A. I discovered several tools that helped me get a handle on the contents of the .exe and .dll files. I should add some detail that was not part of the original posting: I have purposely been using the mingw-w64 toolchain rather than Visual Studio for this development work. So, as it turns out, both ldd and dumpbin helped me get a handle on whether or not the two slightly-different build environments were perhaps leaving me with different dependencies.

B. When I saw that one output included a reference to FindFirstFileExW, which function I had once tried in order to solve what I thought was the problem, I thought I had perhaps found a reason for the different results.  In the event, that was just a red-herring and I do not mean to waste the forum's time with my low-level of experience and understanding, but it seems useful to note this sort of trouble-shooting methodology as a possible assist to others.

C. So what was the problem?  There was, indeed, a small difference in the code between the stand-alone and the ANE-integrated implementations of the recursive directory search. In the production ANE use case, there is logic to apply a level of filtering to the returned results.  The actual application allows the user to qualify a search for duplicate files by interrogating parts of the parent string in addition to the filename string itself.

In one corner condition, the filter may be case-sensitive or case-insensitive and I was using _wcslwr in the mistaken belief that that function behaved the nice, Unicode-compliant way that string handling methods are provided in AIR/Actionscript3. I did not notice that the function actually does an in-place replacement of the original string with one reduced to lowercase.

User error, not, any untoward linking of non-standard CRT Kernel functions by Adobe's Native Extension interoperability, was the culprit.